# What is the appropriate syntax to define EvaluationNodes in CNTK Brainscript

Tags: cntk, brainscript

Using Brainscript in CNTK 2.1 to define a basic network, what is the appropriate way to define multiple Evaluation Nodes?

I have created some custom functions and wish to use them collectively / simultaneously however when I use a comma separated list as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Special-Nodes I encounter the following error

```
[CALL STACK]
                evalNodes = (ce, te, tm)
                   ^
EXCEPTION occurred. while parsing: BrainScriptNetworkBuilder(27): ')' expected
```

When trying the "tag" approach I encounter the following error

```
                ce = ClassificationError (labels, out.z, tag=eval)
                                                 ^
EXCEPTION occurred. while evaluating: BrainScriptNetworkBuilder(21): unknown identifier 'eval'
```

Undoubtedly the issue is PEBKAC although I'd really appreciate a pointer or two on the correct way to achieve this outcome.

Answer (score 0):

BrainScript is case sensitive. Please change evalNodes to EvalNodes. For tag in ClassificationError, please use string for tag:

```
ce = ClassificationError(labels, out.z, tag='eval')
```

Comment: Use of EvalNodes didn't work[CALL STACK]
                EvalNodes = (ce,tc,te,tm)
                   ^
EXCEPTION occurred. while parsing: BrainScriptNetworkBuilder(29): ')' expected

Comment: It can only take one node. If you need to evaluate multiple metrics, please use evalNodeNames.